# Center UIButton with fixed width on AutoLayout for all screens

Tags: autolayout, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I'm still adopting to the AutoLayout thing even though it was release a long time ago. At the moment I'm already using XCode6.

I have this simple Button placed on a particular View Controller in the storyboard. The problem is that I can't display this button centered on each iPhone screen size (3.5", 4", 4.7", 5.5"). Can this be done within the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do this simply with the help of Storyboard.This is the solution:

In Xcode 6 you have a provision for `Add New Alignment Constraints`. in Storyboard.
Over there you have options for `Horizontal and Vertical Center in Container` enable the checkboxes.